# Unusual behavour in PHP IF construction

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I know there´s something really simply I´m doing wrong here but I´ve been playing around with things for hours now, without seeing what´s wrong.
The original code would just output the number of rows counted, but somehow it only gave an output when the number was higher than 0.
So instead I changed it to something where I thought couldn´t go wrong, but still the result is the same. This is the code:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);  
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$usernametmp = $_GET["usernametmp"]; 
$code = $_GET["code"];
$response = "0";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (username = ?) AND 
(code =?)  limit 1");
$stmt->execute(array($usernametmp,$code));

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
{
$response = ($stmt->rowCount());
}
echo ($response);
}
```

Now, the REALLY weird thing is that if I add echo ($response) right after it´s been set to 0 in $response = "0", so that echo ($response) occurs twice, things do what they´re supposed to: When no rows are found, it echos 00, and when a row is found, it echos 01! Of course I could just leave it there, and use the 2nd character to determine the result, but I think it´s important to understand the underlying problem here.

Any ideas?

For chris85 and others who suggested a better way of counting rows. I´ve now changed the code to the below, but still I only get a result if count is NOT 0:

```
<?php
$servername = "x";
$username = "x";
$password = "x";
$dbname = "x";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);  
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$usernametmp = $_GET["usernametmp"]; 
$code = $_GET["code"];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE (username = ?) 
AND (code =?)  limit 1");
$stmt->execute(array($usernametmp,$code));
$response = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 
echo ($response);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty foreach() {} ?

Comment: So comment `echo ($response)` and see the result.

Comment: @Joe Phillips Sorry if that´s not entirely clear: I want to know why this only outputs something when the rows are counted to higher than 0. If the row count is 0, the result is NOT 0, but just.. nothing.

Comment: @Ray Paseur To count the number of rows. Maybe it´s not done in an elegant way, but it works.

Comment: `$stmt->rowCount()` returns you number of rows. Why do something else?

Comment: u_mulder If I do that, the result would be empty in any case. Why should I do that?

Comment: @u_mulder You´re right, thanks - that line doesn´t belong there at all. I got rid of it now, but obviously that´s not the one causing this to act up.

Comment: @Ray Paseur And you´re right as well, like u_mulder - no need for the empty foreach. Still puzzled by what´s going on here..

Comment: Does `echo ($response);` outputs `00` or `01`? Or maybe somewhere else you have echo?

Comment: @u_mulder Running the script the way it shows above outputs nothing if rowcount is 0. If rowcount is 1, it outputs 1. If I add echo ($response) one extra time - additionally after $response = "0", when rowcount is 0, it outputs 00 - first time when $response is set to "0", and the next time for when it´s counted to 0. If rowcount is 1, it outputs 01, following the same pattern.

Comment: Removed the unnecessary line from the code in the question.

Comment: rowCount() isnt for SELECT http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: @Deadooshka What I understand from the link is that it´s not supported by all databases. However, it is by mine or I´d not get it to count 1 when 1 row is found.

Comment: There is only 1 echo in this code so you must be calling this twice somewhere. I wouldn't use the `rowCount` function.

Comment: Among learners, there's some kind of obsession with result-set row counting, something I don't think I've ever needed in 15+ years of career. If you need the actual rows, just use them (why is the exact number important?). If you only need the count, retrieving all rows just to count them is a waste of resources.

Comment: @chris85 There´s only supposed to be 1 echo, but that 1 echo should give me "0" when no rows are counted. It however only outputs something when the number of rows are more than 0. The extra 0 is when testing what happens if adding another echo  ($response) right after the $response value is set before counting the rows, where suddenly it all works as it should.

Comment: @Álvaro González Thanks, so what´s a better method to check if a row exists with a match on $usernametmp and $code?

Comment: @chris85 What would you use instead of rowcount then?

Comment: `select count(*) ... ` then `fetch`, if you are only looking for a count. I'm not sure what you mean with the 2 `echo`s, can you show where you are using the double echo.

Comment: @chris85 Ok, the rowcounting works fine for now but I´ll definately change it later to select count(*) if this is more efficient. For now, the issue is that the script seems to erase the $response value of "0" set earlier in the script, so that it only outputs something when the rows count output a value higher than 0.

Comment: Are you using `empty`?

Comment: @chris85 See the update in my question, using your recommended method. This should clarify better what my problem is - I hope.

Comment: $chris85 Just posted the full script so you can see that there are no things which could interfer with what we´re talking about.

Comment: I start to think something is wrong with the script handling at my host. If I add one more echo ($result); right above the echo ($result); in the last version of the code in the initial question, I get what I should get: 00 if no rows found, and 11 if a row is found. In other words it will only show the count of 0 if I´ve had something - and it seems to not be important what that something is - echo´ed before echo ($result).... I´m really lost here.

Comment: @CoreyHart You know there's a match if trying to fetch the row results in getting a row rather than `false`. But in practice you normally need more than just that: if user is signing in, you'll want additional details: the PK, profile, display name, avatar, email...

Comment: @Álvaro González Absolutely. However this is not the login script but one that verifies a code.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, and could probably use some sanity checks, but it shows the principles I might use.  The query has LIMIT 1, so the maximum row count that can be returned is 1.

```html
<?php // demo/temp_coreyhart.php
/**
 * Working with PDO
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267947/unusual-behavour-in-php-if-construction
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// MODIFIED FROM THE POST AT STACK
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$usernametmp = $_GET["usernametmp"];
$code = $_GET["code"];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND code = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array($usernametmp,$code));

$response = 0;
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    $response = $stmt->rowCount();
}
echo $response;
```

Comment: What does this change?

Comment: It removes unnecessary parts, and to my way of thinking it will be easier to understand and debug.  Since the query has LIMIT 1, the row count will be either zero or one.  You could remove the if() statement, too.  The code snippet I posted was based on the original code snippet, and was an effort to simplify and clarify the original logic, which has been edited out.